# Variable not working in sidebar loop

Tags: loop, sidebar

I have variable working in the loop of my homepage, but when I try to use that line `$variable = $post->post_title; $variable =    str_replace( ' - ', '<br />' ,$variable); echo $variable;` in my sidebar with the same loop, the title disappears.

```
<?php
$recentPosts = new WP_Query();
$recentPosts->query('showposts=9&cat=191,2875,2574');
?>

 <?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>

 <?php $variable = $post->post_title; $variable =    str_replace( ' - ', '<br />' ,$variable); echo $variable; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$post` object is not available outside the Loop, unless you *globalize* it before referencing it:

```
global $post;
$variable = $post->post_title;
```